# Can't use an env file with vscode devcontainer: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I followed [this short official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTU7w3bWrOk) to try using an environment file in my `devcontainer.json` file. I have the same folder architecture than a the video, and my `devcontainer.json` looks like:

```
    "name": "myproject",
    "runArgs": [
        "--env-file",
        ".devcontainer/devcontainer.env"
    ],
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "context": "..",
        "args": {}
    },
```

But I keep getting this error:
`docker: open .devcontainer/devcontainer.env: no such file or directory.` when I run the `rebuild container` or `rebuild container without cache`.

But the file does exist. I can verify it by running `ls .devcontainer/devcontainer.env` in my recovery container.

I even versioned the `devcontainer.env` file and ran `Clone Repository in container volume` again. Still the same error.

Any idea on what's going on?

Comment: I've had a similar issue on and off. At one point I thought it had to do with the shell used for automation tasks having a different profile from the shell used for the integrated terminal. In my settings.json, I set the following: `"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.osx": "bin/zsh",` and it worked after that. But then those settings were deprecated, and I replaced them with "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx". It continued working for a while and then just stopped working again. It's still possibly a terminal issue but I'm not sure

Comment: So weirdly after I left the last comment I was playing around with my settings.json. I edited the following settings:
`  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "zsh": {
      "path": "/bin/zsh"
    }
  }` (I fixed the path from "bin/zsh" to /bin/zsh" and restarted vscode and then tried rebuilding the container and now it's working). So try playing around with similar settings?

Comment: It looks like the context is not correct. move your `Dockfile` to `.devcontainer` and change the `context` to `.`